# ConnectException despite HTTP 200 from server

Tags: java

I am getting this exception despite the fact WireShark shows successful receiving a response:

```
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
at java.net.TwoStacksPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(Unknown Source)
... 18 more
```

And this is WireShark's output (translated):

```
srv->clnt HTTP 1.1 OK
clnt->srv ACK
clnt->srv FIN, ACK
srv->clnt ACK
```

So why the exception?
Worst of all, it's not even in my program so I am not sure how to approach debugging it!
By the way, it's Java 1.7.0_17 and Windows 8.1 (with firewall down).
Also, with curl I am able to access that same URL.

Of course, chance is, the app tries to access some other resource besides that, via god knows what port, but that should not be happening.

Comment: It does look mysterious, and you have already expressed one of the main possibilities that occurs to me: that the exception arises from a different connection attempt than the one WireShark is reporting on.  Indeed, the WireShark results don't show the *establishment* of a connection at all, but rather receipt of some data over an established connections, followed by connection closure.

Comment: If the client's firewall is down, and WireShark does not show traffic that can be associated with the failed connection attempt, then it may be that the client is trying (and failing) to connect to a service on the localhost.  Such traffic might bypass the network stack.

Comment: In any event, there's really not much we can do for you here without having the failing code to look at.